# Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have on my logs this error which I tried to reproduce with different devices but I have never been able to.

`{“headers”:{“normalizedNames”:{},“lazyUpdate”:null,“headers”:{}},“status”:0,“statusText”:“Unknown Error”,“url”:null,“ok”:false,“name”:“HttpErrorResponse”,“message”:“Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error”,“error”:{“isTrusted”:true}}`

This error comes from this function which calls to google api:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
this.http
.post(
“https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/XXXXX/locations/us-central1/models/XXXXXXXXXX:predict”,
file,
{
headers: {“Authorization”:"Bearer "+accessToken}
}
)
.timeout(600000)
.map(res => res)
.toPromise()
.then(
//call then instead of subscribe to form the promise chain.
data => {
resolve(data);
},
err => {
reject(err);
this.utilsService.registerEvent(err,userId,version)
}
);
});
}
```

I don’t know how to solve it and how can reproduce it. It is generating 10 or 15 errors a day. Can anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: Well the error says enough, the URL is unknown. Can you try sending a POST request to that exact same URL via Postman?

Comment: Yes, It works and with all devices I used to test including devices with android 9, 7 and 8. :(

Comment: What error do you receive when you disable your internet just before calling the url on a device?